# Default Button after dispose and setVisible

Tags: java, awt

given the following code:

```
public class DialogTest implements ActionListener {
  public static void main(String[] args) {DialogTest g = new DialogTest();}

  public DialogTest() {
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Button A");
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    JDialog d = new JDialog();
    d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(b1);
    d.add(p);
    d.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b1);
    d.pack();
    d.setVisible(true);
    d.dispose();
    d.pack();
    d.setVisible(true);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {System.out.println("hello");}
}
```

Shouldn't pressing the Enter key write something to the console? According to the docs (http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()):

> The Window and its subcomponents can
>   be made displayable again by
>   rebuilding the native resources with a
>   subsequent call to pack or show. **The
>   states of the recreated Window and its
>   subcomponents will be identical to the
>   states of these objects at the point
>   where the Window was disposed**

Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: I tried running it and it runs fine, not sure why you have a dispose() in your constructor. Can you clarify your question ? what are you asking ?

Comment: While I can't explain the behavior, I can reproduce it. `d.getRootPane().getDefaultButton()` returns `null` once `dispose()` has been called.

Comment: Just being curious. Why are you doing a `dispose()`, then a `pack()` and again `setVisible(true)`?

Comment: @ring bearer: I usually do, but this question was more about the docs and understanding than about daily relevance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in [`JButton.removeNotify`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#removeNotify%28%29) (which seems to be called at `dispose`) the `DefaultButton` is reset:

> Overrides `JComponent.removeNotify` to check if this button is currently set as the default button on the `RootPane`, and if so, sets the `RootPane`'s default button to null to ensure the `RootPane` doesn't hold onto an invalid button reference.

---

```
public void removeNotify() {
    JRootPane root = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(this);
    if (root != null && root.getDefaultButton() == this) {
        root.setDefaultButton(null);
    }
    super.removeNotify();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the explanation. Though I still think the docs should be corrected then or at least be made more specific.

Comment: @DaDaDom: Agreed, the documentation is not complete at this point, and there may be other things too that will not work after a `dispose`. Anyway, `setVisible` is what you really want (as you already know).